# Operation of libraries in C at run time

Tags: c, static, runtime, libraries, shared

I understand that a static library is incorporated in the ELF loadable file. The program and file are loaded as a single 'core-image'.
In a shared-object library is the library 'incorporated' into the 'core-image' at run time to be effectively the same as would have been achieved with a static library?
Or have I missed something?

[50+ years programming and still learning]

I am seeking knowledge and would welcome a URL reference to elucidate.

Comment: Yes, you're essentially correct. The actual implementation uses memory mapping, so all the processes using that library are using the same physical memory. With static linking, each process has its own copy.

Comment: What is a “core-image”? In a typical executable program file, the file describes multiple sections to be loaded into memory, such as a section containing processor instructions (to be read into memory and mapped as execute-only), a section containing constant data (to be read into memory and mapped as read-only), a section containing initialized modifiable data (to be read into memory and mapped as read-write), a section containing zero-initialized data (to be mapped as read-write and initialized to zeros, so not read from the file)…

Comment: … and there may be multiple sections of particular types. A dynamic library adds to this: It has sections to be loaded into memory in addition to the initial executable file’s sections. None of it needs to be a “core image”; sections can mostly be loaded as they are needed: As soon as the program needs a section, the operating system and the program loader can load it then. So a dynamic library does not need to be treated as extra, just as more sections available for loading. A key feature would be the operating system maintains knowledge…

Comment: … of which sections from a file are loaded into physical memory, so that it can map that same memory for different processes that are using it. If it maps that memory at different virtual addresses in different processes, it needs to be written as position-independent code.

Comment: Your notion of core images seems to be from when you started 50 years ago. Operating system design has moved on since then, particularly due to virtual memory.

Comment: Thank you for the information. When I refer to a core-image, I am referring to a virtual core image which I realise will be mapped onto physical memory / swap space / ......    In defence of my antediluvian language, I would point out that the term coredump is still used. I had not considered the possibility of shared objects appearing at different addresses in simultaneous processes.  Thank you for your patience.